# Basic Image Classification using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

```
train = 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\animal train'
test = 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\animal test'
lr = 0.001

def label_image(img):
    word_label = img.split('.')[-3]
    if word_label == "cat": return [1,0]
    elif word_label == "dog": return [0,1]

def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(train)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(train,img)
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),(50,50))
        training_data.append([np.array(img), np.array(label)])
    shuffle(training_data)
    return(training_data)
```

I am new to tensorflow and this is my first project ( Cat vs Dog Image Classification)

Can you please explain each line in detail what is create_train_data() function actually doing?

Comment: SO is not for "explaining each line in detail". You can understand each API call by googling it. For a classification tutorial refer example docs for instance https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

Comment: I already went through that before staring off with this. what is os.path.join() doing here exactly? I understood almost all the program im having doubt here in this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image reading in OpenCV goes as follows
img = cv2.imread("path/to/image", flags)

Now "path/to/image" is either your working directory or absolute path.

path = os.path.join(train,img) in your code is creating absolute path. I think since you are in working directory, just directly reading image also should work in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That answered it